Using Sessions Keys to pre approve transactions within a dApp
I'm pretty new to Solana Blockchain development, and we are working on a dApp solution where users can process multiple transactions at once. We came across this article from Squad which has mentioned that we can use session keys to pre-approve transactions. I went through several sites to check how to implement this, but couldn't find any solution. Does anyone know how we can allow users to pre-approve transactions using session keys as mentioned in the article?
Squads Account Abstraction Use Cases

Session keys is a feature that is currently maintained by magic block:
https://docs.magicblock.gg/Onboarding/Session%20Keys/how-do-session-keys-work
You can setup and example project with session keys using the games preset:
npx create-solana-game gameName 

It creates and anchor program and a js next js client using session keys.
Here is the code in github for the example.
https://github.com/solana-developers/solana_game_preset/blob/main/program/programs/lumberjack/src/instructions/chop_tree.rs

Thank you so much for the information. will check this out.

another question, it seems like Gum is not functioning anymore. is @magicblock-labs/gum-react-sdk still valid?

The gum sdk is the old one i think. They deployed a new program. The old one is not compatible with the new unity sdk version anymore. You can ask them in their discord maybe: https://discord.gg/rqBxPGSB
